# What information do you need when deciding whether to respond to first contact from a company?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

(For those who don't know me, I'm a product manager here at Stack Overflow.)

I've spent a lot of time lately thinking about how to improve the developer experience on [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), especially for developers who have opted in to being messaged by companies that subscribe to our [Candidate Search](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/products/candidate-search) product. Specifically, I'm interested in making it easier and quicker for developers to decide whether or not they're interested in talking to a particular company that sends them a message.

If you have a Careers profile and mark yourself as "looking for a job" or "not looking, but open to being contacted"...what specific pieces of information do you look for in that initial message from a recruiter? What do you see that makes you want to reply? Is there anything you'd like to know that recruiters don't typically include in a first contact? Is there information you'd like to see to help you decide faster which companies are a *bad* match?

Right now this is just a brainstorm; no specific features or schedules are in play yet, though I'm thinking about adding some more structure to the first messages that recruiters send out. (Currently, it's a freeform message, sometimes with a link to a job listing).

How can we structure messages and educate employers so that these first contacts are more valuable to you?

Comment: Maybe you should consider making this a [meta-tag:featured] post? Sidebar looks a little crowded right now though `:/`

Comment: Nah, I don't want to detract from the other featured post @Cupcake...I generally think featured should be reserved for discussions about much larger features/projects, or for important announcements. This is early stages, I'll pay attention to the answers even if they trickle in slowly. :)

Comment: I don't think I've ever gotten an solicited email from a recruiter that I've wanted to respond to.

Comment: @BSMP I'd love to know more about that. What's missing from those emails? (I'd love if you posted an answer expounding on your comment.)

Comment: No SO Careers profile here, but I get a bunch through LinkedIn. I immediately delete any that: 1) Don't identify the company by name. If I can't find it on Glassdoor or Google, then it's spam. 2) Don't disclose the recruiter's affiliations. 3) Don't include information about the job responsibilities/requirements/benefits. I'm not going to consider leaving a good job unless it advances my career, matches my skills more closely, or gives me better benefits. 4) I shouldn't have to say this, but if it's got spelling and grammar errors it's spam. If the writer can't be bothered, then neither can I.

Comment: Why are you contacting me, what can you do for me, what can I do for you, who are you, job duties, interview date/s / open day, some sort of salary idea (it always comes down to the money, why do all the dances to only find out it's a ridiculous offer). Relocation package, benefits. No mail merge rubbish - we as developers can detect that a mile off. And finally, paying people for reems more advice rather than tidbits!

Comment: You could keep the freeform message, and add a message that tells companies to come look at this meta post to figure out how to send good recruitment offers. Though, that's an awfully lazy approach haha.

Comment: Proper grammar and  leave out *"Hi Dear"*

Answer (score 64):

First and foremost, I want to know what the company *does*. Do you build autonomous cars? Open source blogging platform? Do you work in the healthcare industry and build embedded software for EKGs? It doesn't have to be "cool" or *The Next Big Thing* as long as they're open, honest and specific. If I read "we build websites" I'll delete the email on the spot.

Secondly, why did you contact *me*? What did you see in my profile that caused you to say "this dude looks like a fit"?

- "We saw your reputation in the C# tag..."
- "Our system is built in RoR and saw your experience in Ruby..."
- "We read your blog and..."
- "Your contributions to the jQuery project on Github..."
- "It looks like you can do pointer arithmetic in your sleep so..."

Hearing something like that tells me they read not only my Careers profile, but my SO profile, my blog, my Github profile and whatever else I have on there. They took the time to read these things, decide I could be a fit and craft a personal email. I know they didn't just BCC 1000 developers at the same time and wait for responses.

Lastly, I'd like to hear a bit about the culture of the company. Is your office in New York, or in the boonies in North Dakota? Can I work remote? Do you have weekly Beer Fridays™? Can I work whenever I want, or do I have a strict 8-5 schedule? These things are important. I have a family and like to spend time with them, so from the get-go it'd be nice to know I won't be working for slave drivers. It doesn't have to be specific by any means, but a few sentences saying "We're a laid back company yadda yadda yadda" would go a long way.

Of all things, I would say salary is the thing I care to see *least*. I'd be willing to take a pay cut if the company, culture and work sound great. When job hunting, I don't worry about pay until we're done with interviews and both parties agree it's a fit.

Comment: Great answer - I like all this. Having said that, having the salary range up front does help eliminate some stuff, as in my experience similar sounding jobs sometimes have very different salaries attached.

Comment: @RobertGrant true, but for me, I don't want to be influenced either way by money. I'd like the company to stand on it's own. If I know they're offering a really low salary, I might not give it the chance it deserves. Similarly, if I know they're offering a high salary, I might give the opportunity *too much* of a chance when it's really not a fit.

Comment: fair enough :) Now you say that I probably agree!

Comment: I was approached by a company via Careers last year.  It was a "hey, we're building the next Google using Ruby on Rails!"  Ok, that's nice.  I don't know RoR and there's nothing in my profile (SO, Careers, or otherwise) that indicates that I know anything about it.  I get that some places just want bodies, but they could have tried a little harder...

Answer (score 43):

I want to know what the company does and I want to know who you are. I also want to know what positions you are looking to fill. A few details about the position are also important.

---

This is the start of a good message:

[image: Example 1]

It has the following elements:

- Who you are, position in the company and company name
- What you're looking for (two senior developers)

It does not offer the following:

- What the company does (other than "build great software").
- Explanation which of my skills or experiences they are interested in. Are you interested in my Python answers? My projects on Github? My PHP experience from years ago? This is important to know. If the company is looking to recruit me for knowledge I shared years ago (ie. PHP in my case), I'd probably be less useful right now because I haven't used PHP in years. I have not kept up with recent changes to the language or various frameworks.
- Explanation of what the position will do or projects I'll be involved in, or challenges they are facing now that I'll help solve.

---

Another message:

[image: Example 2]

This has the following useful elements:

- I know your name, position and company. Due to who the company was in this particular message, I am even vaguely aware of what the company does

What this does not have:

- A description of the position. "Looking for top talent...to make a significant impact on our systems". Ok. How? What will I be doing?
- How did you find me?

I actually talked to this recruiter and I have to say that I'm both disappointed in the company and myself for not noticing some red flags in this message. This wasn't an interview for a specific position. This was a general recruiting email and I suspect it was sent to multiple users. Flags that I missed in the message:

- Lack of any details at all and use of buzzwords ("top technical talent", "fast paced", "start-up like", "eCommerce industry").
- Discussion about personal career goals and technical background. Some of my back ground should be obvious from my Careers profile, SO profile and links on both. More importantly, I missed the "personal career goals" flag. The details they wanted were to see if my goals aligned with any open positions they had at the time.
- When the discussion took place, the recruiter knew little more than my name. There were no questions about my careers profile (at the very least) or other projects I mentioned on my profile.

Shame on me.

---

Another message:

[image: Example 3]

This message isn't useful to me.

- Who is this company and what do they do?
- I have no experience in mobile apps. How did they find me?
- What is Chad's relationship to the company?

I suspect this message showed up because I work for one of their largest clients, live 10 miles from their office and work, literally, right across the street from them. I didn't know that at the time though. I had to ask a co-worker if they'd ever heard of the company. They pointed out their office at lunch.

---

Last example:

[image: Example 4]

This message is worthless.

- You are seeking employees who are willing to relocate. Great. Good for you. Are you interested in my skills or just a warm body to keep your chairs warm?
- No details about the company, other than a link to a web site
- No name at all. Who am I talking to?
- No details about the job. I hope they found someone to hold their seats to the floor 8 hours a day. If not, I recommend large rocks.

---

I need *details* and I need details more than what the salary is going to be. Obviously, I need to do some research about your company, if I've never heard of you. But, throw me a bone. Tell me a bit about your self. I had to make a fancy resume to get you to reach out to me. I did something that caught your eye. Now, do something that will catch mine.

I don't need to work at a company that is the next Google or Apple or start up flush with cash. But, I do want to know about the company before I talk to you. If you can't spend a few seconds explaining a bit about the company, I don't want to talk with you. I don't think a few sentences is that much to offer:

> "Here at COMPANY NAME, we are looking for a POSITION with skills in LANGUAGE or experience in INDUSTRY. I see you have both and think you'd be able to help TEAM NAME with their on going project of MAKING THE WORLD BETTER. Your PROJECT ON GITHUB looks like you've dealt with aspects of this problem before. We've gotten some press recently about our innovations in this area (check them out HERE)."

Comment: Great writeup, could be a blog post for careers customers.... and yeah, agreed. "We're looking for someone, how about we have a call" is useless. A call is an investment of at least 15 minutes of your life, if not more. There needs to be some level of detail before that.

Comment: This is great, thanks for all the detail and examples! I'm curious about one other thing – if you were to receive a message that had a full job listing attached, would you read it, or is that too much work? Are you looking for a summary in the message itself, or would you prefer the full details, even if it meant clicking through to somewhere else?

Comment: @Laura to me a full job listing in a message reeks of copy + paste -> recruiter/spammer, delete. A link to a full job listing is the way to go

Comment: @Laura I agree with Pekka웃, a full listing would seem spammy. I'd much rather have a short listing with a sentence or two of what the job entails. A link to a posting would then be appreciated. If it was just the link, though, unless they have something else that entices me (ie. "We see the project you did last month and posted on Github does X, we also do X!"), I'm not likely to click on it.

Comment: Love the examples.  Not a single one mentioning why your profile specifically made them want to contact you.

Answer (score 15):

To me, the very first question is what they would need me for. Not in terms of job titles, but in terms of your real-world situation. "We're in our third year building x, our product y is growing faster than we can keep up and we urgently need someone to take over the further development of z". Like to Dave in his answer, it doesn't have to be hip or cool - just honest. (I realize revealing this much detail to a stranger is asking a lot, but that would really stand out.)

The second thing is why they decided to contact me, of all people. Are they just working off a list of users in a tag? Or is there something specific why they think I might be especially suitable (next to the reputation number which, as we know, really means little?)

Then I'd need to know how they plan to deal with the fact that they are far away from me (they always are, even back when I used to live in Germany). Are they expecting me to relocate? Would it be a remote job? Would they be helping me with the relocation? Why do they think the job is awesome enough to justify relocating?

Answer (score 6):

The main thing I'm looking for from any recruiter (here or otherwise) is some evidence they've looked at my skills/experience beyond a simple keyword match. A reference to something specific which makes them think I'd be suitable for the role they have available.

Any generic email which could've been sent to thousands of others (search: 'perl' -> email_all) gets ignored. Unfortunately, this accounts for 99% of all recruitment emails I receive.

Answer (score 6):

When being approached by a company I don't expect much. I want assurances that there are no complete show stoppers from the start.

To that end:

- Where the job is. (Commutable > Relocatable >> Anything in London > Anywhere else in the world.)
- What sort of salary range you're thinking. If your max is below my min, we're just wasting time here. And no "competitive" or "market rate" doesn't count. I know how much I get paid now. I probably can't afford to take a pay cut to work for you. (Theoretically it's possible, but you'll have to be pretty convincing about it).
- A job spec.

Most other stuff is negotiable - but there's a sliding scale on what sort of salary will make it 'worth it' depending on who you are, what you do, how interesting things are, etc. (Relocation assistance and letting me bring my dog to work would help here too!)